# Как создать плагин с вызовом метода shopkeeper3 в modx Revo?

Tags: modx, плагин, revo, корзина

народ.

Полный вопрос:
У меня shopkeeper3, modx REVO. У товаров цена зависит от выбранной опции. (1л - 100 р, 2л - 200 р, 3л - 300 р..). Нашел ответ такой, но опыта не хватает понять что конкретно, как и где нужно делать:

```
Создаем плагин itemPrice
текст:
<?php
$output = 0;
if(!empty($_POST['itemPrice']) && is_numeric($_POST['itemPrice'])){
$output = $_POST['itemPrice'];
}else{
$output = $modx->getOption('price',$scriptProperties,0);
}
$modx->event->_output = '';
$modx->event->output($output);
return '';

Выбираем для плагина системное событие "OnSHKgetProductPrice"
```

Как и где создать плагин и как вызвать метод "OnSHKgetProductPrice". Как понял этот плагин будет менять цену товара в зависимости от опции и отправлять ее в корзину. Как раз то, что мне нужно. На самой странице товара сделал чтобы цена менялась динамически в поле **[[*price]]** на js при выборе соответствующего чекбокс. Но цена не передается в корзину, там всегда 0 рублей.

Answer (score 0):

Помогли на тостере:

у себя в админке идете по адресу /manager/?a=element/plugin/create&category=0
даете название произвольное, во вкладке "системные события" ищите и отмечаете "OnSHKgetProductPrice".
В текст плагина вставляете ваш код, сохраняете.
Ваш плагин должен работать.